# Linguistic corpus design: order elements of different types

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb

I'm trying to design a database for a linguistic corpus search engine. Basically there is a manuscript which contains several songs, and every song in turn contains stanzas and proses. Since stanzas (poetic text) and proses (text in prose) have their own attributes, I decided to "create" two distinct entity types instead of a generic one.

Some of the relevant busines rules are:

- manuscript is in a **1 to n** relationship with song
- song is in a **1 to n** relationship with stanza and with prose

My question is: since in one song there could be both stanzas and proses in any order (es: stanza1, stanza2, prose1, stanza3, stanza4, prose2), I need a way to reconstruct their order. What do you think is the best conceptual way to go to implement this? I've come up with some ideas, but I don't know if they are good or not:

1. "Create" an entity type "position" in a **n to 1** relationship with "song", and put in there a composite PK (fksong and an integer storing the relative order of all the pieces) and some kind of enum or boolean to specify the type (stanza or prose).
2. Just "denormalize", store both stanzas and proses in the same table giving them a type, and order, and store the different attributes in other tables linked in a **n to 1** relationship with it.
3. What I have done in the following logic implementation: create a table "block" in a **1 to 1** relationship with both the tables "stanza" and "prose" and store in it just its auto-incremental ID (referenced as fkblock in "stanza" and "prose") and an integer which represents the relative position of stanzas/proses inside the song.

Is there a better/correct way to do it? Please note I'm using MariaDB.
Thank you in advance.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE poed CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_icelandic_ci;

CREATE TABLE manuscript (
  idmanuscript TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (idmanuscript));

CREATE TABLE song (
  idsong TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fkmanuscript TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idsong),
    FOREIGN KEY (fkmanuscript)
    REFERENCES manuscript (idmanuscript));

CREATE TABLE stanza (
  idstanza SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  stanzatext TEXT NOT NULL,
  fksong TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fkblock SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idstanza),
    FOREIGN KEY (fksong)
    REFERENCES song (idsong),
    FOREIGN KEY (fkblock)
    REFERENCES block (idblock));

CREATE TABLE prose (
  idprose TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  prosetext TEXT NOT NULL,
  fksong TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fkblock SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idprose),
    FOREIGN KEY (fksong)
    REFERENCES song (idsong),
    FOREIGN KEY (fkblock)
    REFERENCES block (idblock));

CREATE TABLE block (
  idblock SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  position TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idblock));
```

Comment: Having two 'identical' tables is usually 'wrong'.  Having two tables in a 1:1 relation is usually 'wrong'.  How would you layout the schema without violating those?

Comment: @RickJames If I had to follow your instructions, I think I'd merge the two similar tables, that is "stanza" and "prose", into a single table, let's say "segment", with its own attributes (text for stanzas/proses, integer for absolute positioning, and eventually a boolean type for filtering), and then establish n:1 relationships between this entity and other entities containing recurrent groups of attributes specific of poetry or prose, or just put them into "segment" and tolerate the NULLS. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Give that a try and see how it feels as you develop the queries around it.

Comment: @RickJames thank you very much!